# How can I configure Apache virtual hosts to run on port other than 80

Tags: windows, apache, port

I've recently upgraded my laptop to Win10 (from Win7). Since doing so I've discovered that something is running on Port 80 so my Apache Local Server won't work as it did. I got lost trying to detect what it was on Port 80 (it's not Skype), so I'm trying to set up Apache to use Port 8080.

I have succeeded up to a point. If I enter 'localhost:8080' in the browser address bar (Firefox FWIW), I get the test 'It works!' message. If I enter my usual virtual host names and append ':8080' it works too. But surely I should be able to get it to work with just 'localhost' etc?

I have set httpd.conf to 'Listen 8080'

I have tried setting the first line of the v-hosts definitions to `<VirtualHost *:8080>` instead of the previous `<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>` but it makes no difference.

I have tried appending ':8080' after the `ServerName` in the V-hosts file (which seems logical) but it doesn't work. I have also tried turning off my Kaspersky Internet Security (but obviously I don't like doing this too much). I have read several articles on Stack Overflow and elsewhere which come close to my problem, but they all assume that the steps I've taken already will be  sufficient.

Is there something else I should have done?

Here is the screenshot from TcpView: 
[image]

Comment: I have tried that but can see nothing on port 80. Apache just fails to start if set for port 80.

Comment: Can you expand that question, please. I don't really understand it as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first screenshot of `tcpview` already shows the process blocking port 80. But it does not say `80`, it was translated into the name of the protocol running on port 80, which (usually) is `http`.

In order to see `80` in the `Local port` column you have to disable translation which can be done through the menu or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl + R</kbd>:

[image: TcpView]

To see more details about the process which opened the port you might want to run `procexp` (with an administrative account).

I think others had the same problem already and a solution to this can be found on a different site on stack exchange: https://superuser.com/questions/352017/pid4-using-port-80

Comment: Thank you. I'm investigating that link. The first thing I notice is that he(?) had the problem in Win7 64, whereas it was AOK in Win7 64 for me, but has gone 'wrong' in Win10 64..

Comment: Thank you. This seems to have worked now (my only reservation being that I've not yet tried every local web site, only those I needed today). I had to go the Regedit route as (it said) the Device Manager route doesn't work in Win>8. I'm back running Apache on Port 80, but no wiser about why it wouldn't work properly on 8080. That doesn't matter for now, but might one day.

Comment: @TimDawson if the problem is solved accept one of the answers to signal the rest of the readers that you are done with it

Comment: I've now marked the problem as solved, because I've got my server running properly again. But actually it's truer to say the problem has been avoided (or the reason I ran into the problem has been removed)! I still don't know how I should have set up to use Port 8080 successfully..

Answer (score 1):

Generallly, in Windows, you have the [IIS (Internet Information Service)](https://www.iis.net/) consuming your port **80**. To stop this service, open the services console and disable that particular service. Alternatively, you can configure IIS to consumer a port other than 80.

---

1. Press Win + R key
2. Type `services.msc` to launch services console
3. Look for IIS service
4. Right click -> disable

That's it.